# AspNet Identity MVC - How to catch Signed In Event

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using ASPNet Identity 2.0 (Full framework, not the core framework) and MVC.
I would like to execute C# code once the user successfully login to the site.

i know that i can write some code right after the `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` command and it will work for new login but not will not work for users who used "remember me" feature and returned to the site later (Cookie authentication).

I am looking for an option to catch the event of all the users who signed in to the site either by entering the password and by using the "remember me" cookie.

Comment: you have a misunderstanding of how authentication works.  being “logged in” is an illusion.  authentication happens on each and ever page access. since you probably don’t want to run this code on each page load, you need to define what exactly a separate login entails.  is it no pages loaded in x minutes?  once you have figured out what that entils the solution should be obvious.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch, I understand the authentication will be on every page and i am ok with this. Could you please advice, where should i put my code? Should it be on the [Authorize] attribute? or there is a specific AspNetIdentity delegate or event i can use for that?

Comment: There are a number of ways to do this.  Override OnAuthentication in you controllers is one way, you can create a global IAuthorizationFilter as well.  There are also several hooks in IdentityFramework itself, which i'm not as familiar with.  There is also the global AuthenitcateRequest and PostAuthenticateRequest, plus AuthorizeRequest and PostAuthorizeRequest hooks.  There are literally way too many ways to do this than I can name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you can do it is by handling the application event in your **global.asax** file.

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                Response.Write("HELLO");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Will fire for every single request handled by the application, css, js, images (maybe). Simply put you could end up doing a lot of checks per request with this idea.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it. You can create and use custom attribute.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        readonly IAuthentication _authentication;

        public CustomAuthorizeAttribute(IAuthentication authentication)
        {
            _authentication = authentication;
        }

        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (!_authentication.Authorize(filterContext.HttpContext))
                filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
          //your code .....
        }
    }
```

And now rather than using [Authorize] use your new [CustomAuthorizeAttribute] attribute

```
[CustomAuthorizeAttribute]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Title = "Welcome";
    ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";    
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're after is FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate (I appreciate Forms-based authentication was not mentioned in the question, but it's an example of Cookie-based remember me authentication, adapt at will)

Unfortunately, there is no trigger for OnCookieBasedFormsAuthenticate_SessionCreate :)

So what you can do is check the Forms-based authentication every so often, because it (and Application_AuthenticateRequest) is fired for every request, CSS pages, images etc, going off to the database to check multiple times per request is an overly resource hungry idea. Luckily the forms cookie ticket has an issued on date and we can use that to check:

```
public void FormsAuthentication_OnAuthenticate(object sender, FormsAuthenticationEventArgs args)
    {
        if (FormsAuthentication.CookiesSupported)
        {
            if (Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(
                      Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value);

                    if ((DateTime.Now - ticket.IssueDate).TotalMinutes > 10)
                    {
                        if(/*Insert logic to check username here with ticket.Name*/)
                        {
                            //recreate cookie with new issuedate
                            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(ticket.Name, ticket.IsPersistent);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                        }
                    }
                    Debug.WriteLine($"{ticket.Name} {ticket.IssueDate.ToUniversalTime()}");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    //Elmah
                    ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(e);
                    //Cannot decrypt cookie, make the user sign in again
                    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new HttpException("Cookieless Forms Authentication is not supported for this application.");
        }
    }
```

This is not the same as cookie expiration, because the user will still retain login status; the user should never see any login request unless there account is no longer valid.